# Custom select if sum>x

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this table :

```
TICKETID | PRICE | NUMBER
```

So for each `ticketid`, the player can pay a price for each number on the `ticketid`.

So if the player wants to pay 1$, 3$ and 4$ for numbers 22,23 and 24 for `ticketid` 25, then the table will look like this :

```
TICKETID | PRICE | NUMBER 
25       |   1   |  22 
25       |   3   |  23 
25       |   4   |  24
```

I want to select a random ticket that has TOTAL PRICE >50, to make it receive a prize.

I also want that the randomization to be fair, and that when doing this draw, each ticket would have only 1 apparition rate. If I don't use DISTINCT or GROUPBY, then a `ticketid` with 10 numbers will have more chances to get drawn than a ticket with 2 numbers.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ticketid),SUM(price) FROM table 
     WHERE SUM(price)>50 GROUP BY ticketid
```

I get the error message

> invalid usage of GROUP BY function

Can anybody help?

Comment: if you use `group BY` you don't need `DISTINCT`

Comment: @valex - correct , but I tried removing DISTINCT and it still doesnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the "HAVING" clause which is applied to any possible candidate records AFTER the group by aggregations have been processed.  The Having is applied THEN and either included (or not) in the final result set.

```
SELECT 
      ticketid,
      SUM(price) TotalPrice
   FROM 
      table 
   group by
      TicketID
   HAVING
      sum(price) > 50
```